# renaming files with list of names that's contains different strings

Tags: python, string, file

I have a folder of images like this

```
img (1).png
img (2).png
img (3).png
```

I also have a list of names that I got from another folder with the same amount of files.
Now I want to rename the images folder with new names using the names in the list.

```
import os
org = os.listdir('C:/Python310/py_scripts/new')
fake = os.listdir('C:/Python310/py_scripts/fake')





org = [i.replace('.PNG', '.png') for i in org]


for i in org:
    for s in fake:
        os.rename(f'C:/Python310/py_scripts/fake/{s}', f'C:/Python310/py_scripts/nw/{i}')
```

the images are in folder 'fake' and the list was from the names in folder 'new' and 'nw' is where I want the renamed images to be.

This is the output

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Python310/py_scripts/fake/0001 (1).png' -> 'C:/Python310/py_scripts/nw/0008.png'
```

Comment: Does the `nw` directory exist? You might want to print out the paths first since I don't think your code does what you intended (the code would copy each fake file many times...)

Comment: The code is not working, because your loop is looping in `dir` of `fake` for each `i` in `org` without recognizing the name of file, you are just looping multiple times on `fake`.

Comment: nw dir exists, What I intended to do was move and rename the files to nw dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import os


org = os.listdir('C:/Python310/py_scripts/new')
fake = iter(os.listdir('C:/Python310/py_scripts/fake'))

org = [i.replace('.PNG', '.png') for i in org]

### If both folders contain the same amount of files.
for i in org:
    os.rename(f'C:/Python310/py_scripts/fake/{next(fake)}', f'C:/Python310/py_scripts/nw/{i}')
```

Comment: Your answer worked! I tried using next and an iter someway but didn't know where to start.
Thanks, I will study your code to fully understand it.